# How to use a stackable Rpi relay HAT to control 220V AC mains power?

Tags: gpio, hat, cable, dht22

So I want to wire two DHT22 sensors (5V) to a Pi and also control a lightbulb with 220V. As a plus this should be very compact and I don't want to solder or use breadboards/jumper cabling.

I looked around and found some nice HATs/boards for the Pi. But there is none which fits my needs, so it seems I need two boards.

Would it be possible to use this board for the lightbulbs:

**Waveshare RPi Relay Board**
[image: Waveshare]

and stack another board on top of this. Something like this

**Paddle Breakout HAT Board**
[image: Paddle Hat]

This would be compact and I could use solid core wire directly or crimp some cables with insulated cord pin end terminal ferrules which I already have.

Will this work or are there some caveats/gotchas which I have to look for? Is it possible to piggyback two GPIO boards on a single Raspberry Pi?

Comment: So you have 220VAC live wire connected to the relay switch on the PCB which is stacked on Rpi?  If your Rpi has a metal case, it it important to earth the case.  Even if you are not using a metal case, you must cover the relay screw terminal with a plastic cover, so your cat won't touch anything dangerous.

Comment: I did not have connected anything, just doing some research....But you are right, I don't want to mess with mains voltage if I can avoid it. Maybe I should go for a 433Mhz socket.

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

> two DHT22 sensors to Pi and also control a lightbulb 220V ... should
>   be very compact  I don't want to solder or use breadboards/jumper
>   cabling. HATs/boards Pi for the lightbulbs Will this work or are there
>   some caveats/gotchas

***Short Answer***

*DON't PLACE ANY 200V Mains Wire near your Rpi!!!*

Beside electric shock risk, there is also scary things like back EMF and EMI that might kill your Rpi.

***Long Answer***

Not too long ago I also did a Rpi project with a couple of sensors, and a relay module with 4 relays, controlling DC and AC mains, very similar to yours.

As I started building my master piece and showing off in a forum, immediately I got severe warnings from all those professionals with EE experience in industry and military areas, including registered electricians.

Now let me first show you my project idea.

[image]

Then the schematic.

[image]

Then I got warnings that I MUST EARTH EVERYTHING (My metal box is 4 metal plates screwed together, and I was told to do earthing 4 times, one earthing to each metal piece.  Oh my goodness, then I regretted to have started the project, or showing off my master piece in the forum! Anyway, I did follow the experts' advice, as shown below.

[image]

I also go severe warning on which good quality wiring, plugs, and which tools to use.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then I started testing.

[image]

What I have not shown here is that my relay box has a 3 meter long input mains wire, and another 3 meters long switched output wires.  And the Rpi GPIO 5V control signal wire going into the box is also 3 meter long.

***In other words, everything mains project thing is 3 meters away from my Rpi!***

As you see, it is a lot of boring hard work.  So I think your idea of buying a wireless socket is good, because you can save much hard labour time to do your Rpi research!

[Best Smart Plugs 2019: The best sockets to make your home smarter - David Ludlow  March 11, 2019](https://www.trustedreviews.com/best/best-smart-plugs-3442666)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I think the wireless socket is more suitable for me.

Comment: Your are welcome.  Have nice Rpi research work!