# Can I use the Sixfab 3G-4G/LTE Base HAT while also using this I2C Shield with my raspberry pi 4?

Tags: networking, pi-4, hardware

I am trying to create a remote weather station but have a problem, apparently I need a HAT that will cover my GPIO pins as well as a I2C shield to connect to my weather monitoring hardware.

Specifically I am using the following 3/4G/LTE Hat from sixfab: [3/4G/LTE Hat](https://sixfab.com/product/raspberry-pi-base-hat-3g-4g-lte-minipcie-cards/)

And the following I2C shield: [I2C shield](https://store.ncd.io/product/i2c-shield-for-raspberry-pi-3-pi2-with-outward-facing-i2c-port-terminates-over-hdmi-port/)

Can I stack the shield on top of the 3-4g/lte hat and expect it to function normally? The HAT is to allow me to connect to my firebase DB while recording the temperature using the shield to connect to my temperature monitoring hardware.

If this isn't possible, does anyone have recommendation's for me on where to go from here?

Comment: I am stacking SIM7600 and other HATs on my Rpi4B, and you might like to see my workarounds: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113992/rpi3b-python-controlling-multiple-sim800-sim900-sim7600-modules.

Comment: Your might also be interested to see my other answers in using stackable HATs including SixFab: (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104705/how-to-tap-tee-fork-stack-the-rpi-gpio-pins-covered-blocked-by-a-hat-p
(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96277/how-to-use-a-stackable-rpi-relay-hat-to-control-220v-ac-mains-power

Answer (score 0):

When you stack HATs on top of each others, you need to verify that the different HATs doesn't use the same GPIO pins.

When I have done this, I used a spread sheet program and document what GPIO pins each HAT uses, and then its quite clear if they collide and uses the same pins.

As for HATs with radios it is always a risk if you cover a antenna with another HAT. That can decrease the radios working parameters to be below whats acceptable. But in your case this isn't an issue since most PCIe cards has external antennas.